# Select range of items from a list until integer value is found

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list with 100 items, the list contains string as well as integers. Something like this:

```
List<string> listName = new List<string>(); 
listName.Add("string1"); 
listName.Add("string2"); 
listName.Add("string3");
...
listName.Add("serial :");
listName.Add("string35");
listName.Add("string36");
listName.Add("string37");
listName.Add("string38");
listName.Add("12");
listName.Add("22");
...
listName.Add("someString");
listName.Add("serial :");
listName.Add("string55");
listName.Add("string56");
listName.Add("string57");
listName.Add("string58");
listName.Add("string59");
listName.Add("string60");
listName.Add("13");
listName.Add("14");
...
```

I want to select items into a string variable, *starting from next index of* `serial` to `int1` i.e., until I find the first `int` value. I was trying something like this, but couldn't come up with proper logic.

```
var serl = listName.Select(x => x.IndexOf("serial :") + 1)
                            .Where(x => x.Equals("serial :"))
                            .TakeWhile(int.TryParse(stringsList.ElementAt(stringsList.IndexOf("serial :") + 1), out int res));
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: `I want to select items, into a string variable`, I think you mean into an `IEnumerable`... Can you tell and or show us how this list is filled, are you filling it like the above?

Comment: Maybe `listname.SkipWhile(x => x != "serial :").TakeWhile(x => x != "int2")`?

Comment: @Codexer: nope! I want it into an string only as I want to compare this again with another type

Comment: Your title is misleading. You have a list of strings. There will never be an integer value.

Comment: @Raj so you want only one string, this doesn't make sense with what you've explained and what you've tried.

Comment: I didn't mention list of strings

Comment: `select items from list` I would assume *more* than one; `items` is plural...

Comment: "I didn't mention list of strings": `List<string> listName = new List<string>();`

Comment: @HenkHolterman: yes there are multiple `serial :` in the list so I thought of keeping a count of `serial :` and than iterating based on the count to copy the range I need. But I just expect a logic to copy the range from the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get lines

```
"string35" .. "string38"
```

So we can

```
                          // <- Skip all lines until "serial :"
listName.Add("serial :"); // <- Skip the very "serial" line
listName.Add("string35"); // <- Take all lines
listName.Add("string36");
listName.Add("string37");
listName.Add("string38");
listName.Add("12");       // <- ...Until 1st integer appears
```

We can implement it with a help of Linq:

```
var result = listName
  .SkipWhile(line => line != "serial :")
  .Skip(1)
  .TakeWhile(line => !int.TryParse(line, out int _ignored));
```

Add `string.Concat` or `string.Join` if you want to have a string instead of enumeration:

```
var strResult = string.Join(", ", listName
  .SkipWhile(line => line != "serial :")
  .Skip(1)
  .TakeWhile(line => !int.TryParse(line, out int _ignored)));
```

**Edit:** If you want to *enumerate* serials (i.e. chunks between `"serial :"` and integers)
you can try implementing **F**inite **S**tate **M**achine with two states (in and out serial):

```
private static IEnumerable<string[]> Serials(IEnumerable<string> source) {
  bool inSerial = false;

  List<string> chunk = new List<string>(); 

  foreach (string line in source) 
    if (inSerial) {
      if (int.TryParse(line, out int _drop)) {
        inSerial = false;

        yield return chunk.ToArray();

        chunk.Clear();
      }
      else
        chunk.Add(line); 
    }
    else
      inSerial = line == "serial :";          
}
```

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: really good one. but what if I want to get to the next set of `serial :` i.e., take lines from `string55` rather than `string35`? `SkipWhile` will stop the search at first index of `serial :` if I'm not wrong?

Comment: @Ashish Srivastava: if we want to *enumerate* serials, we can try implementing FSM (Finite State Machine); please, see my edit

Comment: nice. I like that one and really appreciate your time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If is understand correctly you want to partition your list based on a starting and closing point.

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> BatchPerDelimiter<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicateStart,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicateEnd
)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (predicateStart == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicateStart));
    if (predicateEnd == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicateEnd));

    List<TSource> bucket=null;
    bool picking = false; 

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        // Is the buket empty? because we need a bucket.
        if (bucket == null) bucket = new List<TSource>(); // ??=

        // did we start picking yet?
        if (predicateStart(item)) {
            if (picking) { // Is that a restart?
                yield return bucket; // give the bucket then empty the bucket
                bucket = null;
            } 
            picking = true; // we are picking
            continue; // but we skip this element as it's a starting point
        }

        if (picking) // Are we picking?
        {
            if (predicateEnd(item)) { // Do we stop?
                yield return bucket; // give them the current bucket
                bucket = null;  // empty the bucket
                picking = false; // remember we have stop picking
                continue;   // skip this element
            }
            // just pick it.
            bucket.Add(item);
        }
    }
    //leftover?
    if(bucket.Count!=0)yield return bucket;
}
```

usage :

```
var results = BatchPerDelimiter(
                listName, // input list
                (s) => s.StartsWith("serial"), // condition to start
                (s) => int.TryParse(s, out int _) // condition to stop
            );
```

Viewing the result : You can access the first brunch of serial: `results[0]`, or loop on them.

```
foreach (var batch in results) {
    Console.WriteLine("We have a new batch!");
    foreach (var element in batch) {
        Console.WriteLine("\t>" + element);
    }
}
```

live demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/cDxEFO

Result:

```
Batch #1:
  > string35
  > string36
  > string37
  > string38


Batch #2:
  > string55
  > string56
  > string57
  > string58
  > string59
  > string60
```